# Regular expression to validate set of special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Would anybody please help generate a regular expression to be validated using javascript ?
This regular expression should validate alphanumerical values in addition to the following set of characters:

```
{. - / \ ( ),'}_ + : ? ® © T
```

Thanks and best regards..

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you want a pattern like this:

```
^[\w{./\\(),'}+:?®©-]+$
```

Important things to note:

- `^` and `$` match the start and end of the string, respectively, meaning that only these characters are allowed.
- `[` and `]` define a character class, which matches any of the characters defined inside the brackets
- `\w` matches any alphanumeric character or underscore.
- I omitted `T` and `_` from the character class they are allowed by `\w`.
- `\\` is needed to escape the backslash, because that's a special character in regular expressions.
- `-` must come at the beginning or end of the character class or else be escaped. Otherwise, it would mean something like `a-z` any characters between `a` and `z`.
- Many other characters here have special meaning within regular expressions (e.g. `?`, `+`, and `()`), but it's not necessary to escape them within a character class.
- The `+` on the end means that one or more of these characters is allowed.

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation and not just posting a regex string.